# Double Nested Variables in Jinja

Tags: jinja2, sendgrid, sendwithus

I am trying to put a transactional email in SendWithUs using `jinja`. My data contains a double nest variable.

```
> {   "bookingList": [
>     {
>       "attendees": [
>         {
>           "age": "8",
>           "name": "Tommy"
>         },
>         {
>           "age": "9",
>           "name": "Mila"
>         }
>       ],
>       "classStartTime": "2020-01-30T17:00:00.000Z",
>       "classTitle": "Test class",
>       "count": "2",
>       "price": "10"
>     },
>     {
>       "attendees": [
>         {
>           "age": "8",
>           "name": "Tommy"
>         },
>         {
>           "age": "9",
>           "name": "Mila"
>         }
>       ],
>       "classStartTime": "2020-01-30T17:00:00.000Z",
>       "classTitle": "Test class 2",
>       "count": "2",
>       "price": "10"
>     }   ],   "customerInfo": {
>     "email": "test@test.com",
>     "firstName": "test"   },   "orderInfo": {
>     "orderId": "64d02680-364d-11ea-981c-42010a2ad1c1",
>     "subtotalPaid": "32.09",
>     "taxPaid": "3.94",
>     "totalPaid": "36.03"   },   "subject": "Test 123" }
```

I am trying to get the data to show
These are your enrollment details:
`{{bookingList.attendees.name}}` is enrolled in `{{bookingList.classTitle}}` on `{{bookingList.classStartTime}}`

It is showing the `classTitle` and `classStartTime` correctly, but is pulling in the word `'name'` instead fo the actual name.

How do you treat double nested variables?

Comment: the attendees looks like a list to me. Did you try something like bookingList.attendees[0].name?

Comment: This works! However how do you treat it if you don't know how many people could be attending? There may be 1 or 8?

Comment: for looping through your bookinglist would be your best bet in this case :)

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: I would recommend that you open the documentation of jinja2 and you will see tons of example https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you want to do is a have for loop within a for loop.
Here's a simplified example of what I *think* you're trying to do:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    These are your enrollment details: <br>
    {% for item in bookingList %}
      {% for attendee in item.attendees  %}
      {{attendee.name}} is enrolled in {{item.classTitle}} on {{item.classStartTime}} <br>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Which renders as:

```
These are your enrollment details:
Tommy is enrolled in Test class on 2020-01-30T17:00:00.000Z
Mila is enrolled in Test class on 2020-01-30T17:00:00.000Z
Tommy is enrolled in Test class 2 on 2020-01-30T17:00:00.000Z
Mila is enrolled in Test class 2 on 2020-01-30T17:00:00.000Z
```